# Why backticks are used in node-sqlite3 when names do not contain special characters?

Tags: sqlite, node-sqlite3

I am doing capstone (not reviewable) project for codeacademy pro intensive.

There is an example provided in the lesson.

```
    db.serialize(function() {
      db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Artist` ( ' +
              IF NOT EXISTS  NOT NULL, ' +
               '`name` TEXT NOT NULL, ' +
               '`date_of_birth` TEXT NOT NULL, ' +
               '`biography` TEXT NOT NULL, ' +
               '`is_currently_employed` INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1, ' +
               'PRIMARY KEY(`id`) )');

      db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Series` ( ' +
               '`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, ' +
               '`name` TEXT NOT NULL, ' +
               '`description` TEXT NOT NULL, ' +
               'PRIMARY KEY(`id`) )');

      db.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Issue` ( ' +
               '`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, ' +
               '`name` TEXT NOT NULL, ' +
               '`issue_number` INTEGER NOT NULL, ' +
               '`publication_date` TEXT NOT NULL, ' +
               '`artist_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, ' +
               '`series_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, ' +
               'PRIMARY KEY(`id`), ' +
               'FOREIGN KEY(`artist_id`) REFERENCES `Artist`(`id`), ' +
               'FOREIGN KEY(`series_id`) REFERENCES `Series`(`id`) )');
    });
```

I understand the es6 concept of backticks, and backticks in sqlite3 are used for alternative characters, like spaces. However in this example I don't see why backticks are necessary at all, ex. `Artist`, `name`, etc.?

Can you please kindly help, I am still learning.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL standard and SQLite use double quotes for quoted identifiers. SQLite supports backticks only for compatibility with MySQL.

You are correct that none of these identifiers need to be quoted.

(And I assume the garbage where the `Artist`.`id` column should be is just a copy/paste error.)